# How to trace job status in AWS State machines with C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I submit jobs to state machine like:

```
"Manage Batch task": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:123456789012:job-definition/testJobDefinition",
    "JobName": "testJob",
    "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:123456789012:job-queue/testQueue"
  },
  "Next": "NEXT_STATE"
}
```

Which API can be used to trace the job status in IAmazonStepFunctions[image: screenshot of the the APIs]? I wanna know the jobName, status since there are a bunch of jobs with different names.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Batch job, so the status can be polled by calling  the DescribeJobs from AWS Batch https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html